# Can Cyclops' eye-blasts hurt him?

Tags: marvel, x-men, cyclops

If he accidentally looked at himself without his visor would it hurt him or would he be immune?

Comment: I'd imagine so.

Comment: Nope. He's immune to his own and his brother's powers, and vice versa. I don't really know how to source comic books (and I'd just be copying wikipedia anyway) so I'm leaving this as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: [What types of questions should I avoid asking](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) - "What if ______ happened?"

Comment: @DarthSatan This isn't really a "What if" hypothetical question, of the type you're suggesting it is. It could be worded better, but it's essentially asking if Cyclops is immune to his own energy blasts or not - something very much answerable using canons.

Comment: I remember at least one iteration of the comics where even Havok (Cyclops' brother) wasn't harmed by his blasts.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens In all current incarnations, Havok and Cyclops are immune to each other's blasts.

Comment: @jono - [Scott & Alex](http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20101017213312/marveldatabase/images/0/07/X-Factor_Vol_1_60.jpg) are immune to each other's power but it should be noted that they are not immune to their brother Gabriel's mutation, nor is he immune to theirs. Gabriel (AKA Vulcan) can control the electromagnetic spectrum giving him power over exotic energies such as Cyke's optic blasts and magical energies.

Comment: The Living Pharaoh / Living Monolith is another one who apparently uses the same sort of energy.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the Marvel website, [they cannot hurt him](http://marvel.com/universe/Cyclops_(Scott_Summers)).

> Cyclops' mind generates a psionic field that is attuned to the forces that maintain the apertures. Because this field envelops his body, it automatically shunts the other-dimensional particles back into their point of origin when they collide with his body. Thus, his body is protected from the effects of the particles, and even the thin membranes of his eyelids are sufficient to block the emission of energy.

(*Note:* Marvel has been [historically inconsistent](http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2013/09/27/comic-book-legends-revealed-438/3/) on what the source of Cyclops's blasts are)

On a side note, it's an interesting question as to whether or not a direct shot on the mirror would reflect or just shatter the mirror. There's been some speculation about just what materials Cyclops's beam can bounce off of. The general consensus among fans is that it only works on metal and not on a direct hit, but Uncanny X-men 156 and X-Factor 115 show him bouncing his optic beam off of the ground and into himself and Alex to slow them down (the beams being recoilless, he would not be able to just blast down) with the ground liquefying under the blast even as it reflected it. That would argue that, if the mirror could withstand a direct hit and cause a bounce, it would at least knock Cyclops back with the equivalent force.

All things considered, it's probably easier to take the explanation of "psionic fields" and suggest that Cyclops controls, perhaps subconsciously, what his ability bounces off of and how.

Comment: I've just read that comic and I'm at a loss where the quote about other-dimensional particles comes from

Comment: You would know better than me. :) I'm working off of Wikipedia and other such sites. I can only rely on people correctly linking their sources.

Comment: From Wikipedia:
The original 1983 Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe volume stated that Cyclops' eyes contain inter-dimensional apertures, releasing powerful energies from another dimension into his own via the beams. This account states that his body naturally metabolizes ambient energy that is used to open and focus the apertures in his eyes. The energy of the beam itself originates from this other dimension. This explanation, however, was later changed for the 1986 Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe Deluxe Edition.

Comment: More detail is available at http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2013/09/27/comic-book-legends-revealed-438/3/ but it basically boils down to "Marvel writers keep changing their minds".

Comment: In that comic he covers his eyes with his hands but that's about it. Unless I'm missing a page, there's no technobable whatsoever

Comment: I will remove the attribution and just leave it to "this is the quote from the Marvel site" then. :)

Answer (score 2):

Originally, yes they could hurt him, back when he was created by Stan Lee and Jack Kirby in 1963. Now, for anyone wondering, no, no one ever rebounded one of his beams against him in the original stories. However, it should be noted that on several occasions (The X-Men # 1, The X-Men # 4, & The X-Men # 9 as examples) that when he used his beam at its maximum power output, it caused physical harm, causing him to black out for a brief period. When this happened, the other four X-Men (Iceman, Angel, Beast, & Marvel-Girl) protected Cyclops in his weakened condition, with Beast actually carrying Cyclops around in some stories.